# How Should I Give Int In def discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I want give int and I coded this

```py
async def limit(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.send("Limit is : "+amount)
```

But I Got This Error:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

What Should I Do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the integer to string.

```py
async def limit(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.send("Limit is : "+str(amount))
```

Answer (score 1):

Either cast the integer to a string, format the string or use f-strings

```py
await ctx.send("Limit is : " + str(amount)) # casting
await ctx.send("Limit is : {}".format(amount)) # formatting
await ctx.send(f"Limit is : {amount}") # f-string
```